# View is not sync with component array

Tags: angular

I have the following structure in my service:

```
getAsync(){
    var updateStream = this._http.get('someApi')
        .map(
            res=>{
                var success = res.json();
                ///some logic on success
                return success;
            })
        .catch(
            error=>{
                return Observable.throw(error)
            });

    return updateStream;
}
```

And in my component, I have:

```
Service.getAsync().subscribe(success=>{
   Object.assign(this.myArray,success)
})
```

where myArray was defined as:

```
public myArray:any[] = [];
```

meaning, that it was initialised within the constructor.

Now, in my view, I have:

```
{{myArray | json}}
```

which stays like this:

```
[]
```

all the time.

I've checked with console log's and intervals, that `this.myArray` does indeed change, and the value in the component gets changed.

Where am I making mistake?

**UPDATE**

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RKTHbd?p=preview)

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What data should be shown? Have you tried `oconsole.log(success)` before you return it?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I would like to display the content of myArray. I am working on plnkr now, and I will let you know once I update q

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is not updated when the array is modified, only when another array is assigned to the property.

If you change the line (which is missing the part that assigns the result to `this.myArr`)

```
Object.assign(this.myArr,success)
```

to

```
this.myArr = success; //Object.assign(this.myArr,success)
```

It will update the view.

If the view binds to a property of the items in the array, then `*ngFor` recognizes changes inside the same array but with just `{{myArr | json}}` Angular doesn't recognize the change because the `json` pipe is pure and therefore doesn't get called by Angular until `myArr` has changed.

If you use

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myArr">{{item.name}}</div>
```

then Angular will detect changes within the same array as well.